# Doesn't the existence of non-conservative fields with zero curl contradict the Stokes Theorem?

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

I just saw an exemple of a non-conservative field with zero curl. It is
$$f(x,y)=\left(\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2},\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\right).$$
However the classical Kelvin-Stokes theorem says that
$$\oint_{\gamma} F\cdot\mathrm{d}r=\iint_S(\nabla\times F)\cdot\mathrm{d}S.$$
Because $\nabla\times F=0$, we have that the integral on the right is zero. Doesn't that imply that the integral on the left if zero too?

Comment: Look at the actual Stokes theorem. It is required that the domain is simply connected, while the domain here is not.

Comment: $F$ has to be defined on $S$, the region bounded by $\gamma$. Your vector field $f$ is not defined at $0$: it's a vector field on $\Bbb R^2 - 0$.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Kelvin-Stokes theorem is valid for a **smooth** vector field, but your field is not defined for $(x,y)=(0,0)$ so it is not smooth in a region that contains the origin.